# Long delay before sound and http requests work after log in

Tags: windows-7, windows

I use Windows 7. My computer is fast to boot, and fast to log in. However after I log in, there's a few minutes during which sound doesn't work, and web browsers can't browse websites. Most other applications work okay during this time, although the computer is a little sluggish.

I checked 'task manager' and there's no obvious unusual process.

What's going on?

## Details on websites

Chrome will open and can browse the file system, but requests for web pages hang. Internet Explorer eventually shows a yellow message "google.co.uk isn't responding".

Strangely, during this time, the network is fine - from the command line I can `ping` sites and `http get` websites.

## Details on sound

VLC will appear as if it is playing music, but no sound comes out. I have to stop and start the song to get the sound back. just leaving it won't help.

## Other details

This happens however long I wait after the computer boots to log in, but doesn't happen if I log out and back in. To save me time, I've changed my computer to autologin now.

This has been happening for at least year. I don't remember if it happened when I first got my computer, but I think not.

Comment: Have you checked the events log? And network configuration running `ipconfig /a` on the `cmd` console to see if ip has been assigned. Also, Checked for malware, virus, etc. In short you need to run a full diagnostic to get as much information as possible.

Comment: (1) Does this happen recently or since day one? (2) did you recently install/update/change antivirus/firewall software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled a gazillion items listed by SysInternals' `autoruns.exe` including loads of apple and nokia entries and two audio drivers (msacm mpeg-3 and cinepak codec). Now both the sound and the web work fine as soon as the computer starts. Much less sluggish too. I don't know which was the offending service, or if it was just the effect of having so many (my PC is 5 years old).

This is great - like a new computer

Edit: unfortunately this broke itunes and after I reinstalled itunes my computer is really slow at boot again.

Answer (score 2):

Your HD or filesystem performance maybe degraded (getting slower while loading program, reading files) over time. That compound with Windows delay loading, which only load essential driver/files to show login screen but continue to load other drives, start services afterwords.

To verify, try boot up the machine, and let it sit for couple of minutes before login. You should see the HD light non-stop blinking during that time.

As mention in your own answer, you have tones of program, services starting during startup. You should go through program list in `Programs and Features` in control panel and remove any program no longer needed.